# "crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password"

Tags: go, bcrypt, go-gorm, go-fiber

After registering a user, I try to login with same password but I cannot login due to error. I passed encrypt password and plain password to compare function. But I cannot log in.

```
type request struct {
    PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
    Password    string `json:"password"`
}
var body request
if err := c.BodyParser(&body); err != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnprocessableEntity).SendString("Wrong credentials.")
}
var user model.User
err := model.DB.Where(model.User{PhoneNumber: body.PhoneNumber}).First(&user)
if err.Error != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnprocessableEntity).SendString("Wrong credentials.")
}
matched := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(body.Password))
//matched := CheckPasswordHash(body.Password, user.Password)


fmt.Println(bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte("$2a$14$AphYClfW8V1HZh4.6kSD1OpkTzvS9dTc/1qgKesbCUW5.9BMDmzMW"), []byte("123456")))
//check := CheckPasswordHash(body.Password, user.Password)
fmt.Println(matched)
fmt.Println("Hash pass: "+user.Password)
fmt.Println("Raw pass: "+body.Password)
fmt.Println(matched)

if matched != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnprocessableEntity).SendString("Wrong credentials2.")
}
```

I also print my hash and plain password to check. but I passed all of them.
Here is my console print:

```
crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password
crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password
Hash pass: $2a$14$AphYClfW8V1HZh4.6kSD1OpkTzvS9dTc/1qgKesbCUW5.9BMDmzMW
Raw pass: 123456
!exclude .idea
```

Please help me out or if you have an alternative way to encrypt password and compare it with a plain password please let me know.

Comment: How did you generate the hash? Which value did you use for the cost?

Comment: I don't think the error is with this code. The password does not match the hash. If you create a hash with e.g. `hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("123456"), 10)` and use that in `fmt.Println(bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hash, []byte("123456")))`, it works all fine.

Comment: bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
here is my code

Comment: Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is, but this works: https://play.golang.org/p/TPbK11_sdtC So the error must be somewhere else. Any code that changes the hash? Encoding/Escaping problems etc?

Comment: i dont know. should i reinstall the whole package? actually yesterday's code was running correctly but today I show me a problem.

Comment: Reinstalling the same package code won’t make any difference. You are handling something differently now, but it’s not related to the code shown here.

Comment: @SaifullahShahen commit early, commit often.  One of the best things about version control is being able to find the bug in changes you made from the last working version

Comment: I'm trying to fix this problem. thank you guys for being helpful to me. I really appreciate it and keep helping. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I once stumble upon this problem, and after seeing your hashed password

```
$2a$14$AphYClfW8V1HZh4.6kSD1OpkTzvS9dTc/1qgKesbCUW5.9BMDmzMW
```

notice the forward slash,

I am 100% sure the problem is the same as mine.

that's because you encrypt password from already encrypted password, in other words two times encryption or more.

Answer (score 0):

recently i faced similar issue, later i discovered that my problem was mysql database password field was limited to vchar(30),,got it working after i changed the size